# Python memory issue

Tags: python, shell, memory, memory-leaks

I am currently currently a python code that I believe has some memory issue. 
I reasoned it out last night, I believe it is due to some overheads that's been being constantly generated but I don't know what exactly they are. I have tried `gccollect()` method and it didn't really work. The good thing about my python code is that at each run, I can save the parameters of the partially trained model as pickle. And hopefully, I will shut down the script, and start a new python script and load my saved pickle to continue training.

My strategy is to do the following in a shell script:

```
for i in 1000:
    run `python train_model.py` # this will give me allows a fresh environment with little memory overhead
    # during the runs of `train_model.py`,  some memory overhead has been accumulated
    torch.save(train_model.state_dict())
    shut down the train_model.py script
    # I am hoping that for the next run of this python script, I can get a fresh environment
```

Do you think this will work?  How do I do this in a shell script?

Comment: If you don't know how to do it in a shell script, why not just do it in Python, which you presumably _do_ know how to use? Doing it with the `subprocess` module should only be a little more verbose than doing it with `bash`, and a lot more readable.

Comment: Also, what about just using `multiprocessing`? Then you don't need to worry about save and load to disk; you just create a `Process`, pass it your inputs (which will automatically pickle them), wait for it, read the output, and close that `Process` and start the next one.

Comment: But meanwhile, before doing anything: Why do you believe there's a memory issue? Do you have actual symptoms, like `MemoryError` exceptions or the kernel killing the process for violating resource limits or a performance cliff when the system goes into swap hell or something like that? Or did you just see some scary-looking numbers in ActivityMonitor/TaskManager/whatever? If it's the latter, you might not actually have a problem.